# Is Telephony.Mms/Sms the same across all devices?

Tags: android, sms, telephony, mms

I'm working on an Android project that collects MMS and SMS data. 
I've been learning that it's not safe to use Content Providers to get these data as the specific schema can be different for each device.

I see in Android 19 they added these Telephony.xxx classes that contain MMS/SMS data. Are these safe to use? Are they different than the Content Providers I learned about? It seems like using the telephony class should work regardless of what schema the device manufacturer's use. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: "I've been learning that it's not safe to use Content Providers to get this data..." - Well, that's pretty much the only way to get it. "I see in Android 19 they added these Telephony.xxx classes ... Are these safe to use? Are they different than the Content Providers I learned about?" - Those classes' members are used in interacting with the Providers. They're about as "safe" as can be had. Before API 19, this was all undocumented, so no guarantees then, but the majority of OEMs did use the standard setup. Since API 19, everything _should_ work as documented, but, ya know, there's never 100%.

Comment: LOL so I am back to confident optimism then. At least I can move forward without having to look back again. I'll just have to find an online service that can test my app across many devices. Thanks Mike!